# Is it possible to filter out the low level legendary Pokemon on the GTS?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

I'm attempting to complete my Pokedex, and the GTS is a great way to save some time and effort. However, I've run into the problem of people offering low level legendary Pokemon such as a Level 9 Zekrom for really common Pokemon. From my understanding this is to do some sort of duplication trick or something, regardless it is a wasted slot when I'm attempting to trade. Is there anyway to filter them out these impossible to obtain low level Legendary Pokemon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to filter your searches by what the other player is requesting. You can only use filters to limit the Pokemon you see that other people are offering. The fake trades requesting impossible Pokemon is one of the biggest issues that the GTS has had, and it's unlikely to be fixed (at least not in the current 4th and 5th gen games that have the GTS) as the issue's existed since the first version of the GTS in Diamond and Pearl.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, hopefully X and Y will do something about it.

Comment: The only thing is that Nintendo released a level 1 Dialga, Palkia and Giratina in an event for HG/SS. I think they allow looking for low level legendaries in case they choose to have a similar event again. It does suck though, and would be nice if it was fixed (with a change applied server side when and if they release a similar event again)